# Send textfield contents from iPhone app to webserver (save as .php)

Tags: php, objective-c, webserver

I'm attempting to write an app that allows users to test PHP code within their iPhone. It will take the contents of a UITextField (the content will start with ) and send to a webserver. I need to save the contents as .php and run the code, then echo the output back to the iPhone app. Would anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: What will be in this UITextField - actual PHP code?

Comment: Yes actual PHP code. This will simulate the user have a web server on their iPhone. But all they will see is the output back from my webserver

Comment: What more can you tell us about this application? Who will be the users? Describing the context around the application would be helpful. It sounds like a good idea and I wouldn't give up (as noted in your comments to middaparka)

Comment: The users (as i imagined) were web devs who were given the option to test snippets of code on-the-go (not just at their computer)...what are your thoughts on the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said elsewhere, this is a **massive security risk** as if you're allowing people to enter their own PHP code and execute it on your server, then it could obviously do anything that a native script could.

OK, here'a are a few examples of why this is a *very* bad idea.

1. Script that uses [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) with a for loop to open 'n' hundred processes on your server. Your server grinds to a halt.
2. Script that grabs a high level directory and attempts to recursively delete everything it can find. (Unlikely to cause too much harm if you don't have any odd directory rights and PHP is running as nobody/nobody or similar.)
3. Script that does a `DROP DATABASE` on all databases it has access to. (If you have any defines, database access objects or global variables with DB information in, this is fair game.)

   ...

Comment: Hmmm...can you think of a way to avoid such security issues? Are you saying that in principle this would work, but for the sec issues?

Comment: @benhowdle89 There's unfortunately no way to avoid such security issues. (You could use the safe_mode style lockdowns, but these won't prevent much.) In essence, your letting people run whatever they want on your server and there's no way around that. That aside (and to be honest, that's unfortunately a concept killer) what you're attempting isn't that difficult - all you're really doing is uploading a file which is no biggie. (There are lots of existing "how to upload a file from iOS" questions.)

Comment: @benhowdle89 Probably for the best. (Interesting idea, though.) You could of course create your own language-ette and parser in PHP, but I suspect that would defeat the purpose of the app.

Comment: @middaparka - Giving up so easily? Was your thought that this capability was available to everyone? Were you thinking of this as a script capability? Perhaps extending your first question with some context around the idea may produce different results.

Comment: @Frank C. Er.. I'm not the OP. That said, if by "giving up so easily" you think there's some means of locking this down, by all means add a suggestion. :-)